# i want select name form one table and display in my page

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT name from tbl_gallery, tbl_gallery_category where 'name' = 'gallery-cat-id';
```

I have `two tables` one for `category` and `second` for `saving images` with category name my query is here 
 Then executing thien shows  `MySQ`L returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0007 seconds.)

Comment: reomve single quotes in  name instead of  'name'

Comment: Are you sure `name = cat_id`?

Comment: yes  name contains gallery-cat-id

Comment: @javis then check answers bellow.

Answer (score 2):

Remove single quotes in name instead of 'name' [read when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

If you put single quotes on table or column name, they are treated as string so don't put.

```
SELECT `name` 
FROM tbl_gallery 
JOIN tbl_gallery_category ON tbl_gallery.name = tbl_gallery_category.gallery-cat-id;
```

Note :

```
where 'name' = 'gallery-cat-id';
```

above where condition is always false only. Because your just comparing 'name' is equal to 'gallery-cat-id' so that it's false .

Answer (score 2):

Don't use quotes on table or column names.

```
SELECT name 
from tbl_gallery
join tbl_gallery_category on tbl_gallery.name = tbl_gallery_category.`gallery-cat-id`
```

If you need to escape a column name then use backticks.